# Different type of E-torx Sockets

Tags: bolts, wrench

Are there different types of E-Torx socket.
Today I had to take out a bolt on the engine mount which was a bolt compatible with an E-18.
I have both E-18 spanner and E-18 1/2 drive socket. However the socket doesn't fit/sit properly whereas the spanner fits properly which led me to this question. Upon close look I saw the teeth marks are slightly different even though they are both E-18.

[image: E18 spanner]
[image: E18 socket]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your socket is Torx, but your spanner (and the bolt) are the newer Torx Plus design.

Torx Plus was introduced in abut 1990, when the original Torx patents were going to expire. It has an improved shape particularly for high-torque applications.

Standard Torx drivers will "sort of work" on Torx PLus fasteners, but they are a loose fit.

See https://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/-/media/web/sef/resources/docs/other/torx_plus_brochure.pdf for details of the different shapes.